# How to add the mandatory start symbol (username *) to the textview in android without using two another view like imageview or textview

Tags: android-layout

I have to implement the required fields indicator for text view I have taken two text view in linear layout and implemented can any help me without using another view.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Username" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="*" android:textColor="#fcf90303" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:text="Username"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:text="*"
    android:textColor="#fcf90303"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

Comment: Please next time use the "[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35403788/edit)" option-*on the left below your post right below tags used in your question*- to update or edit your question instead of using comments